# Is this correct usage of perfect infinitive?

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense, infinitives, perfect-infinitive

My question comes from this [Present perfect VS infinitive verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267764/present-perfect-vs-infinitive-verb), where they explained that the sentence

```
He became the first 16 year old to have scored a goal for his country
```

is grammatically incorrect and you should use

```
He became the first 16 year old to score a goal for his country
```

instead. But lately I came across this article https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Shaw_(strongman), which included this sentence:

> In 2011, he became the first man to have won the Arnold Strongman Classic and the World's Strongest Man contest in the same calendar year

I guess it might be correct, because I consider this site as a respectful source with very low chance of grammar mistakes. What's the difference between two "have" usages and why the first case is not correct, while the second (at a great chance) is?

Comment: *I guess it might be correct,*... No, it's wrong.

Comment: The answer to the linked question is incorrect. Your first example might be stylistically "clunky", but it's not "incorrect".

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22became+the+only+man+to+have+won%22) are several more written instances of the sequence ***became the only man to have won*** in Google Books. There's nothing *syntactically* wrong with the usage - it's just that in any context I can think of, it's semantically equivalent to the much simpler *...only man **to win** [whatever he won first]*.

Comment: Wikipedia is a respected source? It sure is handy, but there's no reason to assume a crowd-sourced page is correct in content or language. None.

Comment: I personally find both "he became the first to score" and "he became to first to have scored" equally acceptable, though the latter (with "have") seems more proper. In general, not using "have" in the context of something becoming something or acquiring some property would result in the predicate shifting to past tense: "He was the first to score." The tense of "became" and "was" seem to agree in this respect, which is perhaps why I see no issue with "became" without "have".

Comment: Certainly, "he is the first to score" (present tense) doesn't give the intended meaning, and to me suggests a property guaranteed to be held in perpetuity or for some extended period of time; the meaning is more akin to "He will be the first to score (today/every game this season/always)." Is there even ever a proper application of present tense in such constructions?